# Using ControlFX Range Slider, how to highlight entire window

Tags: javafx

This was previous question - [How to Highlight section of a Javafx window using Range slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765700/how-to-highlight-section-of-a-javafx-window-using-range-slider)

I could not submit MRExample in time so it was voted to close. I am reposting here the same thing.

For a project in Javafx, I need to create a Wave form generator for given set of data like this

[image]

I have created everything else but not getting how to create section highlighter using sliders on top. I have marked the area as "How to do this part?" in the above image.

My work:

[image]

I used RangeSlider for the sliders in the pic above, but how do i make it highlight the whole window that falls under the RangeSlider. While I have seen this in audio processing apps, what is the best way to do it in Javafx ?

Minimum Reprod. Example->

Main.java

```
    package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;



public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("RangeSliderExample.fxml"));

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,500,500));
           
            primaryStage.show();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="459.0" prefWidth="554.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="554.0">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" layoutY="13.0" prefHeight="439.0" prefWidth="543.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

import org.controlsfx.control.RangeSlider;

public class Controller implements Initializable  {
    
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    
        RangeSlider rangeSlider = new RangeSlider(0, 10000, 0, 100);
        rangeSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        rangeSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        rangeSlider.setMinorTickCount(10000);
        
        
        HBox sliderBox = new HBox();
        sliderBox.getChildren().add(rangeSlider);
        
        scrollPane.setContent(sliderBox);
        rangeSlider.setPrefWidth(10000);
    }

}
```

RangeSlider JAR can be downloaded from:

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.2/controlsfx-11.1.2.jar
```

The output (and what I need) - RangeSlider inside scroll pane which will highlight the whole window area below it for selected range

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Compared to the example below, it would likely be *cleaner*, though probably not *easier*, to implement this by creating a completely custom control.

---

The general idea is that you need to know the positions of each thumb in the `RangeSlider`, and then bind the `Rectangle` (or whatever you use) to that information. This will involve getting access to the thumb nodes, listening to their bounds, and translating those bounds between the different coordinate spaces. Luckily JavaFX provides APIs to make this relatively easy.

The example below modifies your `Controller` class. It relies on the default skin of the `RangeSlider` and uses `lookup` to get access to the thumb nodes. The creating of the rectangle and the binding of its properties occur in a listener on the `skin` property of the slider. This is needed, because the skin will not have been created at the time the `initialize` method is being invoked. The rest is just relatively basic math.

To have a transparent rectangle, you just need to set its fill to a color whose opacity is less than `1.0` (100%). The below code sets the fill to `#1E90FF7F`, which is `Color.DODGERBLUE` with an opacity of `0.5` (that's the `7F` at the end).

Please note that this example is highly specific to the code you provided in your question. The general concept should be applicable to your real code and other scenarios, but you likely won't be able to directly copy-paste the following.

```java
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.controlsfx.control.RangeSlider;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Controller implements Initializable  {
    
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    
        RangeSlider rangeSlider = new RangeSlider(0, 10000, 0, 100);
        rangeSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        rangeSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        rangeSlider.setMinorTickCount(10000);
      
        HBox sliderBox = new HBox();
        sliderBox.getChildren().add(rangeSlider);

        // added this
        rangeSlider.skinProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Skin<?>> observable, Skin<?> oldValue, Skin<?> newValue) {
                if (newValue != null) {
                    observable.removeListener(this);

                    Node lowThumb = rangeSlider.lookup(".low-thumb");
                    Node highThumb = rangeSlider.lookup(".high-thumb");
                    
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    rect.setFill(Color.valueOf("#1E90FF7F"));
                    rect.setManaged(false);
                    rect.setMouseTransparent(true);

                    rect.yProperty().bind(rangeSlider.layoutYProperty().add(rangeSlider.heightProperty()));
                    rect.heightProperty().bind(sliderBox.heightProperty().subtract(rect.yProperty()));

                    rect.xProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
                        Bounds bounds = lowThumb.getParent().localToScene(lowThumb.getBoundsInParent());
                        bounds = sliderBox.sceneToLocal(bounds);
                        return bounds.getCenterX();
                    }, lowThumb.boundsInParentProperty()));
                    rect.widthProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
                        Bounds lowBounds = lowThumb.getParent().localToScene(lowThumb.getBoundsInParent());
                        lowBounds = sliderBox.sceneToLocal(lowBounds);
                        Bounds highBounds = highThumb.getParent().localToScene(highThumb.getBoundsInParent());
                        highBounds = sliderBox.sceneToLocal(highBounds);
                        return highBounds.getCenterX() - lowBounds.getCenterX();
                    }, lowThumb.boundsInParentProperty(), highThumb.boundsInParentProperty()));

                    sliderBox.getChildren().add(rect);
                }
            };
        });
        
        // added this
        StackPane content = new StackPane(new Label("Some background text"), sliderBox);
        StackPane.setAlignment(content.getChildren().get(0), Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        StackPane.setMargin(content.getChildren().get(0), new Insets(20));
        
        scrollPane.setContent(content); // changed content from 'sliderBox' to 'content'
        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true); // added this

        rangeSlider.setPrefWidth(10000);
    }

}
```

Demonstration:

[image: GIF demonstrating example]

Comment: I don't have words to thank you and am in awe of your extensive knowledge...Respect !